# javascript call methods of managed bean on start-up and doesn't call them on command button click

Tags: javascript, jsf, spring-data, managed-bean

I'm working on a web application project using JSF, Maven, Spring-Data framework and Neo4J graph database.

here is a sample JSF page from my work

```
// JSF Sample Page
…
<h:commandButton value="button" onclick="fun(#{bean.doWork()})" />
…
```

and a sample JavaScript page from my work

```
// JavaScript Sample Page
…
function fun (var_value) {
…
}
…
```

and a sample Managed Bean class from my work

```
// Managed Bean Sample Class
…
public int doWork() {
…
}
…
```

**The problem is:**
JavaScript calls the method of managed bean on start-up (I don't know why).

**The big problem is:**
JavaScript doesn't calls the method of managed bean on command button click.

**Note:**
when clicking on the command button it calls the JavaScript function but doesn't calls the method of managed bean and work with the data which loaded on start-up from calling the method of managed bean

**Another Note:**
when calling the method of managed bean on command button click directly without using JavaScript function it works fine and doesn't calls the method of managed bean on start-up (it seems that this is the solution of my question, but I have to use JavaScript)

Comment: What is `var` here in this JavaScript function `function fun (var) {...}`? It is a reserved keyword that cannot be used as variable name. Observe the browser console for any JavaScript error. This Java method is not syntactical (syntactic) `Public int doWork() {...}`. It won't compile. Note the capitalization (`P`) here in the beginning `Public`.

Comment: @Tiny sorry, I have been updated my questions, it was bad of writing not syntax error

Answer (score 0):

When your page loads, bean function will be called and it will fill your JavaScript with return value. You can check that if you view source of the page. After that, when the page is loaded, if you click the button it will use old value, it won't call bean method again. You would need to update/render that part of the script first to update the value, and then call the JS method.
I hope I wasn't too confusing...

**Example:**

```
//JSF page

<p:commandButton value="button" action="#{bean.doWork}" update="script" oncomplete="fun()" />
<h:panelGroup id="script">
  <script>
    function fun () {
     var var_value = #{bean.workResult}; 
     …
    }
  </script>
</h:panelGroup>


//Bean

 private int workResult = 0; //so it doesn't report error at the beggining
 public int getWorkResult() { return workResult; }
 public void doWork() {
   …
   workResult = valueYouWouldReturn;
 }
```

Comment: I know, but i don't want to load these methods on start-up, it makes the web application too slow. Also, how to update/render the JavaScript on command button click ?

Comment: I edited my answer, you can try something like that.

Comment: it works, please refer to the second note in the question, I have to use javascript

Comment: If you by " I have to use javascript" mean that you don't wan't the page to refresh, then you can change h:commandButton to a4j, primefaces or richfaces button (if you use something of that). You can't just call bean function from your JavaScript code. JS is on your client side, and bean is on server, so you need to send some request to get the value.

Comment: unfortunately, I need to refresh the page, I need to refresh it every 5 minutes at least

Comment: I meant to refresh it on button click. But, anyway, can you explain to me why do you need to use JavaScript?

Comment: I'm using javascript with google charts, I need to get values from bean to graph it.

Comment: I forgot to add oncomplete attribute for the button where you call your js function. Also, button is now p:commanButton, as primefaces component. If you use some other framework, just use their button with ajax request and options to add oncomplete.

Comment: I used that, but there is error in mime type for JavaScript, can't solve it.

Comment: it works, but still getting the old value, it only get the new value when refresh the page

Comment: I edited my answer again. I think this should work... Script is now in panelgroup and i realised I don't need f:ajax when using primefaces button...